# Computing SHA-1 for a directory

Tags: java, hash, directory, checksum, sha1

I'm trying to a compute a SHA-1 checksum for an entire directory structure.

What I have done so far is to recursively compute the SHA-1 for each regular file and append all the checksums together. The problem is that this makes the computing dependent on the order of traversing the files

I.e if I have a folder containing the files

`file1.dat file2.dat`

and the other folder containing the same files, but ordered by

`file2.dat file1.dat`

this will compute different checksums.

How can I make the SHA-1 computation order independent?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just order the files in a directory before iterating over them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options with that:

1. Create a archive file, for directory and then create the digest for it. (zip, jar)
2. Read all file bytes into single byte array and then create from it the digest.
3. Pre-order data before you create the digest, using your algorithm.
4. Create a two list of digest and compare them.

Personally I would go with option one, is fast and easy.

Comment: 1 won't work, since the file order in the archive is not guaranteed to be the same. 2 won't work, since you ignore file boundaries, e.g. two text files "a" and "bc" will create the same hash as the two files "ab" and "c". 3 probably won't suffice either, since the file names are not considered when creating the hash.

Comment: @jarnbjo, thanks for pointing that out. Point 1, 2 and 3 must have preodered data to work properly. But this is not a big problem. In addition comment of point 2, boundariesdepend on need if we care only to validate the contentet of file this can be ommited. Please feel free to add you own solution of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try sorting the file names String[] you get from File.list before calculating SHA-1 , or File[] for File.listFiles, File is Comparable. Arrays.sort is enough. Note that File.list / File.listFile return items in no particular order, though they may seem sorted.

Comment: asenovm should also consider using the file name as part of the hash calculation and not only the file content.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you already have the hash calculation algorithm ready you could just add all the hashs in a Set (or any other data structure that doesnt take the order of the elements important) and for each directory and then check if the sets are equals

[Set Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: I'm computing one of the hashes on a server, and the other one on a client.

Comment: If you really want hash, then you will take the order as part of your protocol, lets say the hash must be calculated using the files and dirs in alhabetical order, or maybe you could use File names like @Evgeniy Dorofeev posted, and send files and dirs names over the network